# user_id and user properties don't show up in reports

Tags: google-analytics

we just released GA4 to our ecommerce shops but I have a problem with some custom dimensions and user properties. At the moment when I create a report and use our user_id as dimension it only shows up as "not_set".

What I did:

- We push the the following information to the datalayer (user_id and crm_id). Both have the same values.
- I created a datavariable in GTM to fetch the user_id and crm_id
  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1vnvF.png)
- I added those fields to the GA4 base config tag and to the other events (like add_to_cart)
  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kEHfo.png)
- I added a custom dimension (user scope) called "crm_id" in GA4
- In DebugView data is shown for those user properties
  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AWuh9.png)
  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oVp5h.png)

The result: all data regarding "crm_id" is not set.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7HoWB.png)

Does anyone know what I did wrong?

Answer (score 2):

It seems that we have a similar issue: [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/229134128) is our ticket on the GA4 issue tracker.
We've created it on Apr 14, 2022. As for today (that is Apr 18, 2022) there is no any response.
And we've also found another tickets indicating that smth went wrong with User Properties in GA4 in March (before March everything worked fine for us too): [this](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/221097894) and [this one](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/228588452). There were some replies from the support team but the solution was not provided and the tickets are still open.
Maybe you should also leave your comments there to gather interest for the issues.

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved? I'm also having issues with user id not tracking.

Comment: For us the issue was automatically gone since May, 18 (as it was for other reporters). Nothing was changed from our side.